# Many to Many with additional table in L4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a schema like that:

[image: schema]

And now I want to use it in Laravel 4. So far, I could only achieve getting games for certain user, without touching `owntype`. Code:

```
public function games() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Game','games_users','owntype_id','games_id')->where('user_id','1');
}
```

The only thing I'm getting is `onwtype_id`. How can I add `owntype` table to the "equasion"?

Answer (score 0):

You can access extra pivot table columns by specifying them through the `withPivot` function on the relationship function.

Basically I think you want to do this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game', 'games_users')->withPivot('owntype_id');
    }

}

class Game extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'games_users')->withPivot('owntype_id');
    }

}

class Owntype extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'owntype';

}

// Now you can do:
foreach ($user->games as $game)
{
    // Echo each Owntype description.
    echo Owntype::find($game->pivot->owntype_id)->description;
}
```

For the record... I think you might be taking it too far by creating a new table for `owntype`. Just set the description as a `type` column on the pivot table. Also make sure that your pivot table is named `game_user` (singular, alphabetically) and Laravel will know which pivot table to use automatically.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game')->withPivot('type');
    }

}

class Game extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('type');
    }

}

// Now you can do:
foreach ($user->games as $game)
{
    // Echo each ownership type.
    echo $game->pivot->type;
}
```

Some more info about working with pivot tables can be founded in [the Laravel 4 docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).

Comment: I tried your solution and it returns "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$games".

Comment: Can you paste your exact code? You can use http://paste.laravel.com if you want. Also paste the models, please.

Comment: I managed to come out with your solution for the first code. But isn't there any way to ommit `echo Owntype::find($game->pivot->owntype_id)->description;` and instead, get `type` from the query earlier? This solution causes too many queries.

Comment: Don't know for sure. You can always create a statement by just using joins to connect the pivot and owntype tables. In that way you only have to create a single query.